# PHP syntax error

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I have been trying to get the syntax of following query right but it keeps on generating Syntax error

**Code Example**

```
$_SESSION['FN'] = "FirstName";
$_SESSION['LN'] = "LastName";
$_SESSION['Code'] = 1;
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName,LastName,Code) VALUES("'.$_SESSION['FN'].'","'.$_SESSION['LN'].'",'.$_SESSION['Code'].')";
```

I want to store string and integer value but insert statement generate syntax

Comment: what are you doing with the `$_SESSION` variables?

Comment: You code is vulnerable to sql injection. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @piddl0r That depends on where the variable values come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is bad, 
the correct form is:

```
 /* i don't need this!!!
    $_SESSION['FN'] = "FirstName";
    $_SESSION['LN'] = "LastName";
    $_SESSION['Code'] = 1;
*/
    $strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName) VALUES("'.$_SESSION['FN'].'")";
```

o if the fields of table BookingInformation  are, for example, FirstName, LastName and Code,
you can insert :

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName,LastName,Code) VALUES("'.$_SESSION['FN'].'","'.$_SESSION['LN'].'",'.$_SESSION['Code'].')";
```

if you have some values null, you can do:

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation   VALUES("'.$_SESSION['FN'].'",'','')";
```

Answer (score 3):

You're quoting is wrong such as

```
VALUES("'
```

Should be

```
VALUES('"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName, LastName, Code) VALUES('" . $_SESSION['FN'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['LN']. "','" . $_SESSION['Code'] . "')";
```

Also your code is vulnrable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Session variables are usually held server-side with a session-key in a client-side cookie.

Comment: Never assume something is safe to use ;-)

Comment: ERROR :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /hermes/web08/b978/pow.habtoorfootballcom/htdocs/alfarooqcentre.com/Bookings/test.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the '' are inside the "" try the following way:

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['FN']."', '".$_SESSION['LN']."', '".$_SESSION['Code']."')";
```

You are also trying to insert 3 values into one row which can't be done like the above, it should be (pseudo code):

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ($data1, $data2, $data3);
```

Or in your case:

```
$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName, LastName, Code) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['FN']."', '".$_SESSION['LN']."', '".$_SESSION['Code']."')";
```

Lastly your code appears to be insecure as the session may be tampered with, better to secure all inputs with prepared queries or `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

try

`$strSql = "INSERT INTO BookingInformation (FirstName, LastName, Code) VALUES('".$_SESSION['FN']."', '".$_SESSION['LN']."', '".$_SESSION['Code']."')";`

Comment: Code field  is Integer '".$_SESSION['Code']."' do i still have to write the query as it is

Comment: then, you can use it without the double quotes.

Comment: A VERY IMPORTANT POINT is you should do input validation. This line of code assumes that you are sure there is nothing nasty in these variables. `SQL Injection` is a very common way of attacks.